# How to implement scaling by dragging view edges/corners like Apply Official Photos app crop control?

Tags: ios, image, resize, edit, crop

The apple official photos application have a edit function which you can crop photos. I would like to implement a similar control for cropping photos. I would like to know how to implement the resizing of the crop mask.

The resizing of the crop mask have the following requirements.

1. The crop mask can only be resizing by dragging edges or corners.
2. The anchor point of scaling is opposite the the start edge or corner.
3. The crop mask can have aspect ratio lock.
4. The crop mask should not go belong a restricted bounds.

I have done the first 3 requirements, but the 4 requirement is troubling me. Consider a case where the crop mask is at its minimal size at the restricted bounds box bottom left corner. Dragging the top edges will make the view scale with anchor point at the bottom left corner. With this strange behaviour, I think my implementation of changing bounds with opposite anchor point cannot have this behaviour. So I think the apple implementation is different from mine. And I would like to know how these behaviour can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

The question is what procedure have you even taken.

I would suggest this is done with a simple `UIScrollView`. Your "crop mask" can be the scroll view which may be resized and repositioned by dragging the corners of it. The scroll view must have the "clip subviews" disabled so you may see the content view outside the scroll view (the content view being the actual image).

So this procedure will already save you all the trouble with bounds when scrolling the image. Moving the scroll view will still have a bit of work... Depending on which corner you are dragging you might need to modify the content offset as you seem to have already figured and should give no trouble at all. Then what is left is putting the image into the crop mask when it gets out of bounds which should be done by calling scroll rect to visible for the whole content view frame; if not it can be easily computed manually as well.

You must also override the hit test method so that the scrolling will happen outside the scroll view.